# make PageView view fast scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pageviews

i had a pageView, i use a code from dave to have some views on the same screen, like gallery widget, but the problem its seems its kind slow, not sure how to modify the ontouch event, what can i do to make fast scrollig i had this PageScroll code

```
public class PagerContainer extends FrameLayout implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    boolean mNeedsRedraw = false;

    public PagerContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //Disable clipping of children so non-selected pages are visible
        setClipChildren(false);

        //Child clipping doesn't work with hardware acceleration in Android 3.x/4.x
        //You need to set this value here if using hardware acceleration in an
        // application targeted at these releases.
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        try {
            mPager = (ViewPager) getChildAt(0);
            mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The root child of PagerContainer must be a ViewPager");
        }
    }

    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return mPager;
    }

    private Point mCenter = new Point();
    private Point mInitialTouch = new Point();

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mCenter.x = w / 2;
        mCenter.y = h / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        //We capture any touches not already handled by the ViewPager
        // to implement scrolling from a touch outside the pager bounds.
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mInitialTouch.x = (int)ev.getX();
                mInitialTouch.y = (int)ev.getY();
            default:
                ev.offsetLocation(mCenter.x - mInitialTouch.x, mCenter.y - mInitialTouch.y);
                break;
        }

        return mPager.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //Force the container to redraw on scrolling.
        //Without this the outer pages render initially and then stay static
        if (mNeedsRedraw) invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mNeedsRedraw = (state != ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
    }
}
```

and this its the web where i take the code:
[PageView code](https://gist.github.com/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1) and this is the image of what i get [image: PageView Result] since Gallery its depreacted this should be used, and gallery throws me outofmemory exception because im using images (i tried asyntask and a lot of things) Thanks